# objective-c storyboard outlet and file owner connection issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

I am pretty new to ios, objective-c and xcode.  Trying to learn by building a simple app using collection view. I am not sure I got the outlet and file owner's set and linked properly.

I am getting following error:

> 2015-01-16 08:15:19.711 test[4548:187055] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[ViewController loadView], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UICollectionViewController.m:166
>   2015-01-16 08:15:19.713 test[4548:187055] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the
>   "tzI-IH-vJx-view-Jhf-9m-MoA" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'

I have a storyboard.  It has a View Controller.  Within the View Controller, I have a View.  Within this View, I have Collection View.  Within this Collection View, I have CollectionViewCell. Within CollectionViewCell, I have Image View. I am not sure how these should be connected.

Here is my code and I can't put up a screen shot, I just joined. Can someone help.  This should be easy but I spent quite of bit of time.

Thanks

```
==========================


ViewController.m:

#import "ViewController.h"

#import "Cell.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSArray *myArray;
}


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end

===============================
ViewController.h:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end


==============================

Cell.h:


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *itemImageView;

@end


=============================

Cell.m:

#import "Cell.h"

@implementation Cell

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you associated your `ViewController` class with the view controller object in the storyboard, then what you should ensure is that the `view` binding for `ViewController` is set properly to the `collectionView` object. I hope the image below will make clearer what you should check:

[image]

You will also notice the 2 bindings dataSource and delegate: make sure that the `collectionView` `dataSource` and `delegate` bindings are bound to the view controller.

On another coin, I do not know what you are trying to do, but you could find it easier to instantiate a `UICollectionViewController` in the storyboard. That will give you all of the above already nicely set up. (Unless you are trying to have a collection view that only takes a part of the screen.)